# Access denied magento admin custom login?

Tags: magento

Access denied magento admin custom login?
i can't access login custom admin third party extension
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go To
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php

Line No : 74 and change from 
return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin');
to
return true;

Answer (score 0):

add this method in admin controllers of the extension:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('ENTER RESOURCE IDENTIFIER HERE');
}
```